# Sides of a issosceles trapezium with non parallel sides of 30 cm and a parallel side equal to 30 cm is readjusted so as to make its area maximum.

Tags: geometry

Sides of a isosceles trapezium with non parallel sides of 30 cm and a parallel side equal to 30 cm is readjusted so as to make its area maximum..What should be the smallest angle between a parallel side and a non parallel one so as to make its area maxmimum.

This came in kvpy 2017 sa.

There were 4 options

a)pi/2

b)pi/3

c)pi/4

d)pi/6

Now this one where i could not even proceed one line..

Here to me pi/6 is the correct answer as one needs maximum area and one side will remain fixed.

I would like to know how others do this problem.

Comment: What does readjustment mean here?

Comment: readusting the angles

Comment: @dp SO the length of non parallel sides will change? Or is it to remain constant?

Comment: length of non parallel side will remain the same

Comment: length of only one parallel side will change other one remains fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce an angle $\theta$ as angle from other parallel side to the non- parallel side. Using the areas of triangles, we can find area of trapezium as:

$$\begin{align}A &=  \frac{1}{2}30\sin\theta \, (30+30+2\cdot 30 \cos\theta) \\
 &= 900\sin \theta \, (1+\cos \theta) 
\\ &= 900 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cos^{3}(\theta/2) \sin(\theta/2)\end{align}$$

This is maximised for $\theta = \pi / 3$